# Erro no armazenamento de nomes em arquivo.txt

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

//inicio do programa

main()

{ //cria estruturas

typedef struct {

char nome[10];

} movimentacoes;


//cria as variavéis

FILE *arq;

movimentacoes nome;

//recebe o nome da conta

int i;

for(i=0;i<5;i++){

printf("Digite o nome:\n ");

gets(nome.nome);

}

//abre o arquivo para gravação

arq = fopen ("nomes.txt", "a");


//grava os dados no arquivo

fprintf(arq,"%s", nome.nome);


//fecha o arquivo


fclose (arq);



}
```

Só está armazenando o ultimo nome colocado(quem quiser editar fique a vontade,sou novato aqui)

Comment: Exatamente, você está colocando a abertura, gravação e fechamento do arquivo fora do loop e portanto só o fará para o último dado lido. Se você quiser gravar 5 arquivos então coloque as instruções de manipulação do arquivo dentro do loop.

Comment: verdade,o que uma chave não faz.. kkk

Comment: fiz aqui,armazenou todos os 5,porem o ultimo ficou em primeiro,não é necessariamente um erro,mas deu isso

Comment: Tem certeza de que o arquivo já não existia anteriormente criado em uma execução da versão do programa com erro? Note que você está utilizando append.

Comment: Para este caso especificamente seria melhor você abrir o arquivo, fazer um loop lendo e gravando cada nome e ao final fechar o arquivo. Também pode abrir o arquivo com "w" para recria-lo a cada execução do programa.

Comment: vou verificar se existe,tentei com o w mas só leu o ultimo nome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente estruturas de dados são declaradas fora das funções.

Percebi alguns erros no seu código:

- Você só declarou apenas uma estrutura ao invés de um array para receber os nomes dentro de um loop, nesse caso cada interação do loop vai sobrescrever o anterior terminando com apenas um nome.
- Na hora da escrita você escreve apenas um nome, mas se você quiser escrever os 5 nomes que leu, você precisar criar um loop para iterar sobre o array e escrever cada nome do array no arquivo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char nome[10];
} movimentacoes;

int main() {
  // a - Modo de apender.
  FILE *fp = fopen("nomes.txt", "a");

  // Verifica se houve algum erro ao acessar o arquivo.
  if(fp == NULL){
    printf("O arquivo não existe ou o usuário atual não tem permissão para acessá-lo.");
    return 1;
  }

  // Declara 5 estruturas.
  movimentacoes m[5];

  // Ler 5 nomes.
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Digite um nome: ");
    scanf("%s", m[i].nome);
  }

  // Escreve os 5 nomes no arquivo.
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", m[i].nome);
  }

  // Fecha o arquivo.
  fclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```